# RewriteHeader - Helicon ISAPI Redirect Old URL

Tags: isapi-rewrite

There are instructions in the Helicon documentation on using the RewriteHeader http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#RewriteHeader and even one example which does exactly what I am looking for:

*And this rule will add Old-URL header to the request, providing a Request-URL as a header value:*

```
RewriteCond URL (.*)
RewriteHeader Old-URL: ^$ $1
```

I've added these two lines as the first two lines of my httpd.ini, stopped and started my website, recycled my application pool (neither of which should be required)... but I can't see any Old-URL header anywhere. I have been going to various URLs, ones with or without redirection rules and haven't been able to find the header. I have been using Chrome's Network tab to review the pages coming back from the server (with status of 301 and 200 respectively)

All redirects in the file are working fine.

Update: There are multiple ways redirects can happen in our current project and I want to add HTTP headers so I can see which method the redirect was fired from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the rule like this:

```
RewriteCond URL (.*)
RewriteHeader Old-URL: .* $1
```

Or consider using [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) which is more straightforward and has logging to easier debug the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. We will be changing to use the inbuilt IIS redirects eventually.